# SAP HANA Cancelling Connections

Tags: hana

We have a Java application where we connect to SAP HANA and get the data. Facing an issue of SAP HANA cancelling the connection as shown in the below `IndexServer` logs. And in the Java application we have UI Tabs, hence multiple calls are happening. sometimes only few tabs are failing with below error and other tabs are success. Somehow HANA has a limit of connections or so and not allowing for new connections.

On the Java side we are getting the error as

> com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc40.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection to database server lost; check server and network status [System error: Socket closed]

`IndexServer` logs:

> 18144]{-1}[-1/-1] 2018-09-19 10:41:01.335210 i SQLSessionCmd    Connection.cc(08190) : cancel requested for 312203 (logical connection id is 312203)
>
> [10943]{-1}[-1/-1] 2018-09-19 10:41:01.335240 i SQLSessionCmd    Connection.cc(08190) : cancel requested for 312202 (logical connection id is 312202)
>
> [14796]{-1}[-1/-1] 2018-09-19 10:41:01.335753 i SQLSessionCmd    Connection.cc(08190) : cancel requested for 312201 (logical connection id is 312201)
>
> [18144]{-1}[-1/-1] 2018-09-19 10:41:03.384314 i SQLSessionCmd    Connection.cc(08190) : cancel requested for 312198 (logical connection id is 312198)

Can anyone provide the reason for SAP HANA cancelling these connections and any queries to check in SAP HANA?

Comment: Looks like the sessions had been cancelled on the server side. What timeout settings have been set in this database? Also, what HANA version/revision are you using?

Comment: I dont think its the issue with timeout as we are getting the error immediately and Hana version is Hana 2 sps 2 revision 23. Moreover, out of 7 parallel calls, sometimes all are failing. Sometimes, 2 got success and 5 got failed.

Comment: But it is consistent like always only those 2 get success and other 5 calls will always fail.